# Loading data into a named graph in GraphDB using the REST API or the RDF4J API

Tags: graphdb, rdf4j

I wanted to see if there is a way to create and load data into a named graph in GraphDB. I have tried the GraphDB RDF4J API to `http://127.0.0.1:7200/repositories/repo1/rdf-graphs/urn:abc:123`.

This works, however it creates a named graph called `http://127.0.0.1:7200/repositories/repo1/rdf-graphs/urn:abc:123` as opposed to `urn:abc:123`.

Here is the spec I was following: https://rdf4j.org/documentation/reference/rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me in Python:

```
import requests

file_path = <PATH_TO_YOUR_TTL_FILE>
graphdb_repo = <YOUR_REPO_ID>
named_graph_uri = <YOUR_NAMED_GRAPH_URI>

with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-turtle', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

upload_url = f'http://localhost:7200/repositories/{graphdb_repo}/rdf-graphs/service?graph={named_graph_uri}'
requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, data=file_content)
```

Or in CURL:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-turtle" -H "Accept:application/json" -T "<PATH_TO_YOUR_TTL_FILE>" http://localhost:7200/repositories/<YOUR_REPO_ID>/rdf-graphs/service?graph={YOUR_NAMED_GRAPH_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing directly and indirectly referenced graphs.

From the spec you posted section [Graph Store support](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/reference/rest-api/#graph-store-support)

> <RDF4J_URL>/repositories//rdf-graphs/ (for directly referenced named graphs). A request on a directly referenced named graph entails that the request URL itself is used as the named graph identifier in the repository.

So you are using directly referenced graph and this is the desired behavior.

Also see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66087694/graph-store-protocol-support-in-graphdb/66369529#66369529) answer could be of help